# Playwright - Can't launch Chromium when it's in node_modules (Azure Function - Linux and Windows)

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, playwright

I made an Azure Function that uses Playwright. It works locally, well, that part doesn't change)

Then I created Azure DevOps pipeline, so it uses Ubuntu agent, builds it with `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0`, so the Chromium is downloaded to `node_modules` (and I see it there). Then it's released to Linux Azure Function.

But when the function runs in Azure this line:

```
  const crBrowser = await chromium.launch({
    executablePath:
      "./node_modules/playwright-chromium/.local-browsers/chromium-827102/chrome-linux/chrome",
  });
```

throws this error:

> Error: spawn ./node_modules/playwright-chromium/.local-browsers/chromium-827102/chrome-linux/chrome EACCES
> =========================== logs ===========================
>  ./node_modules/playwright-chromium/.local-browsers/chromium-827102/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees,ImprovedCookieControls,SameSiteByDefaultCookies,LazyFrameLoading --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-JZVt2S --remote-debugging-pipe --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --no-startup-window
> ============================================================

I tried this with Windows and Linux - same thing, just different wording.

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-headless-chromium-puppeteer-playwright/

Comment: This is where it came from.

Comment: I have the same problem when building and deploying through Azure DevOps pipeline. Did you solve this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony Chu (the author of the article mentioned in the comments and the one that made me to try this in the first place) replied that he hasn't been able to make it work with playwright-sharp. It only works with puppeteer-sharp.